# grep out unique senders from a huge list of emails

Tags: centos, email, grep, regular-expressions

I just found a huge list of emails under my user account in Centos /home/user/mail/new

I opened some of them and noticed they were sent from a particular cron job. From address is `root@hostname.com`. I need to find out if all these emails were sent by `root@hostname.com` - It's about 30GBs of email. Is there a way to grep out a list of unique list of From addresses? The format of the email is something like this:

> Return-path:
>
> Envelope-to: user@hostname.com
>
> Delivery-date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 04:34:02 -0400
>
> Received: from user by hostname.com with local (Exim 4.69)
>
> (envelope-from )
>
> id 1QrQiI-0004qM-6V
>
> for user@hostname.com; Thu, 11 Aug 2011 04:34:02 -0400
>
> From: root@hostname.com (Cron Daemon)
>
> To: user@hostname.com
>
> Subject: Cron  /opt/gsn/reports/pr.sh
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
>
> Message-Id:
>
> Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 04:34:02 -0400
>
> [MESSAGE CONTENT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ grep -E '^From:' /some/file | uniq
```

Comment: `-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long` - what can I do about this?

Comment: Use split to split the source file up into chunks.

Comment: It's not one file, each email is about 20K, and the total emails amount to 30G.

Answer (score 1):

To get total number of emails, run:

> grep  From: /home/user/mail/new | wc -l

to get the count of emails from root, run this

> grep  ^From /home/user/mail/new | grep root\@hostname.com | wc -l

now (Total emails) - (emails from root) = actual number of emails from total emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/^From: / { print $2 }' /home/user/mail/new | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

> It's not one file, each email is about 20K, and the total emails
>   amount to 30G.

```
awk '/^From: / { print $2 }' /home/user/mail/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```